# how to make the button event write the output in a textfield

Tags: java, javafx, event-handling, addeventlistener, hbox

how to make the button event write the output in a textfield since the button is
in a hbox and the other in a textfield because i am using borderpane.
 at the end of the action event the button should write in the textfield the choosen file signature
what is the solution of this problem?

```
public class Filrsystemencryption extends Application 
{

private HBox getHBox() 
{  
 HBox hbButtons = new HBox(15);
 Button btnimport = new Button("import");
TextField textfieldd = new TextField ();
  btnimport.setOnAction((event) ->
   {



  btnimport.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() 
  {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

 JButton open = new JButton();
 JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
fc.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("C:/Users/hannah/Desktop"));
fc.setDialogTitle("choose a file");
fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
if (fc.showOpenDialog(open) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
  textfieldd.setText("file chosen");
}
        }

    });

 Button btnDelete = new Button("Remove");
 TextField textfield = new TextField ();

 final ComboBox ComboBox = new ComboBox();
    ComboBox.getItems().addAll(
        "Encrypt",
        "Decrypt"   
    );

Label label = new Label("password");
hbButtons.setSpacing(30);
hbButtons.setPadding(new Insets(10, 20, 30, 20)); 
hbButtons.getChildren().addAll(btnimport, btnDelete, 
label,textfield,ComboBox); 
  return hbButtons ;
}


  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {


   BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
   pane.setTop(getHBox());
   pane.setCenter(getHBoxx());


primaryStage.setTitle("File system encryption");
Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 600, 600);
primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.show();
}   
  private TextField getHBoxx() {

 TextField textfieldd = new TextField ();
 textfieldd.setPrefWidth(400);
 textfieldd.setPrefHeight(200);
 return textfieldd;    
   }

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }

  }
```

Comment: Why mix Swing classes like Button and JFileChooser with JavaFX classes in this app?  That just looks wrong.

Comment: Here is how to [format code using idea](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/reformatting-source-code.html), try to do that for the code you post using that technique or one that is applicable to your source editor.

Answer (score 1):

Using Swing classes in JavaFX when it's not really necessary just results in problems with the main threads for both platforms. Better use [`FileChooser`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/FileChooser.html) for files and for directories (like in this case) [`DirectoryChooser`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/DirectoryChooser.html):

```
btnimport.setOnAction(evt -> {
    DirectoryChooser dirChooser = new DirectoryChooser();
    dirChooser.setInitialDirectory(new java.io.File("C:/Users/hannah/Desktop"));
    dirChooser.setTitle("choose a file");

    File choice = dirChooser.showDialog(btnimport.getScene().getWindow());

    if (choice != null) {
        // dialog not aborted
        textfieldd.setText("file chosen");
    }
});
```

Comment: Wher should i write this function??

Comment: Simply replace your own broken `setOnAction` part (where you try using a naomymus class AND a lambda expression) with my code.